# Python syntax error when tryng to generate oauth2 token

Tags: python, mutt, gmail-imap

I'm having a problem in running a command to get offlineimap running. I'm not an expert and don't code in python.

I need to run the following command:

```
python python/oauth2.py --generate_oauth2_token \
       --client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID --client_secret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET
```

And I'm using the following repository to access the oauth2.py: [gmail-oauth2-tools](https://github.com/google/gmail-oauth2-tools).

The problem is that when running the command I'm getting the following syntax error in the .py file:

```
File "oauth2.py", line 297
print 'Missing options: %s' % ' '.join(missing)
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Below is the block of code where the error is contained:

```
    def RequireOptions(options, *args):
      missing = [arg for arg in args if getattr(options, arg) is None]
      if missing:
         print 'Missing options: %s' % ' '.join(missing)
         sys.exit(-1)
```

For more reference, what I'm trying to do is listed in this document: [offlineimap.conf (line 946)](https://github.com/OfflineIMAP/offlineimap/blob/master/offlineimap.conf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem, running `python2 python/oauth2.py` instead of `python python/oauth2.py` fixed it for me (you need to have python2 installed on your system)

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot. I'm trying to get mutt to work with gmail but it has been a pain.

Comment: Yeah, it's annoying as hell, but it's worth it.

Comment: @Erik Sorry for getting late to the party :) I'm receiving same error, using Python 3.8.1. I typed: python oauth2.py ----client_id=##id --client_secret=##secret